# One Entity Framework definition with two storage providers?

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

**Setup**

- I have a SQL Server 2008 database that is accessed using the Entity Framework on the server.
- Each client has a SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 database for storing data when offline.
- I use self tracking entities that are generated from the server defined Entity Framework.

**Question**

At the moment i have two EDMX defined, one for the server and another for the client, even though they are identical except for the storage provider. I use the self tracking entities from the server and they work fine with the client database. Is there a way to have just a single EDMX? At the moment there is a risk I will make a change to one EDMX and forget to make it to the other. Or am I using the wrong approach?

**Note**

I do not want to use the sync framework because of complex business logic that needs applying at the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to use single EDMX with multiple storage providers. You must always have separate SSDL part for each provider. The common workaround is to [export SSDL, MSL and CSDL as separate files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716709.aspx) (default setting adds them as resources to assembly) and use some script or pre-build action to create copy of SSDL file with all necessary changes for second provider (there can be also different data types between SQL Server and SQL Server CE). You will than use correct SSDL file per application by specifying it in connection string.

Another "better" solution is not using EDMX and use code first where this problem mostly doesn't exist - but that is architecture change.

Comment: Wouldn't the script need to be a post-build action because the latest SSDL/MSDL/CSDL are generated during the build and so a pre-build script is to early?